# View localhost from Iphone using MacBook Pro

Tags: iphone, macos, localhost, ip-address

So I am attempting to view my localhost from my Mackbook on my iPhone. I am attempting to do so through USB connection with developmental modes on in Safari in both devices. I've tried to connect to localhost 2 ways so far with no success:

1. First I've opened up my System Preferences on my MacBook. I opened up the sharing option. Then I clicked "Internet Sharing" toggle on the left. I noted my computer name and clicked the option "iPhone USB." I then navigated to `<cpuname>.local:4200,` with 4200 being the port I'm using in for localhost. This has Safari saying that it cannot reach the server.
2. Second I opened a terminal and typed "ifconfig" to find my CPU IP address. I then attempted to navigate to my localhost from my phone using `<cpuip>:4200` This also failed with Safari saying that it could not connect to the server.

I have done no other configurations and am interested in hearing what I should do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Extra Info**
The application is a simple Angular application.
Both devices are connected to the same network.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody suffering this problem, I've found a solution using the hint from [this](https://zeph.co/iphone-localhost-mac) link here. The solution was to bind the host to port 0.0.0.0. In the Angular 2+ way, that would mean serving the app with the `--host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck` flags. Good luck!